# Assembly + Meta Data + Assembly Manifest + MSIL CODE

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, assemblies, exe

Can any one will answer the following questions. I am using c# language.

1. Can I call Assembly as .ddl or .exe file?
2. Can I call Assembly Manifest as assembly?
3. What is different between Assembly, meta data and Assembly Manifest?
4. Can I say

   .DLL or .EXE = Assembly + Meta Data + Assembly Manifest + MSIL CODE.

Please help me to clear these questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1** -- An assembly *can be* a single a .DLL or .EXE file, but *not all .DLLs and .EXEs are assemblies*. Assemblies are specific to the .NET framework.  Both .EXE and .DLL assemblies can be referenced or loaded by your .NET application.

**2** -- The assembly manifest is just one part of the assembly that contains metadata describing the assembly.  [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w45z383%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the assembly manifest:

> - Enumerates the files that make up the assembly.
> - Governs how references to the assembly's types and resources map to the files    that contain their declarations and implementations.
> - Enumerates other assemblies on which the assembly depends.
> - Provides a level of indirection between consumers of the assembly and    the assembly'simplementation details.
> - Renders the assembly self-describing.

You can add and change some aspects of the assembly manifest from your code if you need to change the metadata associated with that specific assembly. The assembly manifest may be stored as its own physical file, but it is still considered part of the assembly.

**3** -- The assembly is composed of CIL code, metadata that describes the types defined by the CIL code, the assembly manifest which is metadata that describes the assembly and other resources such as static images needed by the assembly.  Therefore, the assembly manifest is just one part of an assembly as is the metadata.

**4** -- Almost. **Assembly = MSIL Code + assembly manifest + type metadata + resources.**

The assembly can be compiled into either an .EXE or .DLL file, but can also be comprised of multiple files.

Answer (score 3):

Lets start with these concepts (in simple) then we will have our answers
**Compilers** are syntax checkers and “correct code” analyzers. in .Net platform regardless
of which compiler you use, the result is a managed module. A managed module is a standard
32-bit Microsoft Windows portable executable (PE32) file or a standard 64-bit Windows
portable executable (PE32+) file that requires the CLR to execute.[image]

**IL code** Code the compiler produced as it compiled the source code. At
runtime, the CLR compiles the IL into native CPU instructions.

**Metadata** Every managed module contains metadata tables. There are two main
types of tables: tables that describe the types and members defined
in your source code and tables that describe the types and members
referenced by your source code. 
**Assembly** is an abstract concept that can be difficult to grasp initially. First, an assembly is a logical grouping
of one or more modules or resource files. Second, an assembly is the smallest unit of reuse,security, and versioning. Depending on the choices you make with your compilers or tools,you can produce a **single-file or a multifile** assembly. In the CLR world, an assembly is what we would call a component. 
(The CLR doesn’t actually work with modules, it works with assemblies) 
**Assembly Manifest** is **part of the assembly** that describers set of files inside the assembly
[image]
An assembly allows you to decouple the logical and physical notions of a reusable, securable,versionable component. An assembly’s modules also include information about referenced assemblies (including their version numbers). This information makes an assembly self-describing. In other words, the CLR can determine the assembly’s immediate dependencies in order for code in the assembly to execute. 
 
actually when using C# compiler, generatin .DLL Or .EXE will be done using a compiler option so DLL and EXE are equal components in  assembly concepts.
So we will have 
1- Correct, Assembly is Maneaged DDL(s) or EXE files
2- No, The assembly manifest is just part of the assembly
3- Described in the answer 
4- Managed .DLL or .EXE = Assembly (Containing Meta Data + Assembly Manifest + MSIL CODE)

Images and some of the quotes from [jeffrey richter](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780735627048.do)

Answer (score 0):

From the excellent book **Pro C# 5 and the .NET 4.5 Framework**:

When a *.dll or *.exe has been created using a .NET-aware compiler, the binary blob is termed an
***assembly***.

An assembly contains ***MSIL code***, which is conceptually similar to Java bytecode in that
it is not compiled to platform-specific instructions until absolutely necessary. 
Typically, “absolutely
necessary” is the point at which a block of MSIL instructions (such as a method implementation) is
referenced for use by the .NET runtime.

In addition to MSIL instructions, assemblies also contain ***metadata*** that describes in vivid detail the
characteristics of every “type” within the binary. For example, if you have a class named SportsCar, the
type metadata describes details such as SportsCar’s base class, which interfaces are implemented by
SportsCar (if any), as well as a full description of each member supported by the SportsCar type. .NET
metadata is always present within an assembly, and is automatically generated by a .NET-aware
language compiler.

Finally, in addition to MSIL and type metadata, assemblies themselves are also described using
metadata, which is officially termed a ***manifest***. The manifest contains information about the current
version of the assembly, culture information (used for localizing string and image resources), and a list
of all externally referenced assemblies that are required for proper execution.